# Store and Access Xml elements using Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Subject>
  <Book>
    <Name>ASP.NET</Name>
    <Author>ABC</Author>
    <Published>2018</Published>
    <Price>$100</Price>
  </Book>
</Subject>
```

The above is xml file i have . I want to Store those xml nodes and values in Dictionary and also i need to access the values by using corresponding nodes.
Then only it will works ..

What i have tried is:

```
  XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("myxmlfile.xml");
                Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    string field = "";
                    string strlayer = "";
                    bool Name = false;
                    int count = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    XmlNodeType nt = reader.NodeType;
                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            switch (reader.Name)
                            {
                                case "Subject":
                                    count = 1;
                                    break;
                                case "Book":
                                    count = 1;
                                    break;
                                case "Name":
                                    if (count == 1)
                                    {
                                        strlayer = reader.Value;

                                        MessageBox.Show(strlayer);
                                    }
                                    else
                                        Name = true;
                                    break;

                            }
                            break;
                    }

                }
```

Am trying the code but its not working.Anyone's help is appreciable ....
i just want to store for that value to that Particular node That's it....

Comment: "It's not working" could mean virtually anything. Be specific and detailed and complete. Tell us exactly what you expect your code to do, and exactly what it does instead. **Help us to help you.** If there's an exception, tell us exactly what exception and on exactly what line. However, you shouldn't be working with XML this way in .NET. [Use `XDocument.Load(filename)` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-an-xdocument-vs-querying-an-xelement), and learn to work with XDocument.

Comment: [Here's another tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples).

Comment: am trying to display the output as "node - value" format in message box , but am seeing the message box empty after running the code and also am trying to store node with respective value in dictionary

Comment: "am trying to store node with respective value in dictionary" is not a complete and detailed description of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDocument.Load("YOUR_PATH");

    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (XmlElement item in xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("Subject/Book"))
    {
        dict.Add(item.Name, item.InnerText);
    }
```

if you have only one "Book" element this code help you. but if you have several Book item so you can not use a dictionary to save them.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq ;

namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Book").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }

    }
}
```